# PHP MYSQL, error Insertando datos

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo un problema, ya escribí mucho código y borre mucho código y a la final siempre se me da el mismo error.

Ocurrio un error:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`avision_bd`.`tb_producto`, CONSTRAINT `r_producto_compania` FOREIGN KEY (`id_compania`) REFERENCES `tb_compania` (`id_compania`))

Les explico tengo una tabla llamada **tb_compania** esta en esta tabla tiene los campos de *id_compania*,*id_usuario*, *id_categoria*, *c_compania* aquí todo bien.

Como bien saben cada **compania** tiene sus **producto** o **servicios**, esos datos los guardo en otra tabla, llamada **tb_producto** y tiene los campos de *id_producto*, *id_compania*, *p_producto*

Entonces cual es la lógica que yo uso, cuando yo tengo mis datos de **compania**, me voy para el apartado **producto o servicios**. ahí usando **sesiones** le digo que si el **id** de la **sesión actual** es igual al **id de usuario** entonces que me muestre el **id de la compania**

así

```
<?php
include 'session.php';
include 'Config/ConexionBD.php';

if (isset($_POST['btn_producto_servicio'])) {
$query_sql = "SELECT MAX(id_compania) as id FROM tb_compania WHERE 
id_usuario = '$login_id';";

if (!$query_sql) {
    echo 'No se pudo ejecutar la consulta: ' . mysqli_error($conn);
    exit;
}
if ($a = mysqli_query($conn, $query_sql)) {
    while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_row($a)) {
        echo 'Su id es : ' . intval($fila[0]);
        echo '<br>';

        #if (isset($_POST['btn_producto_servicio'])) {
        $id_compania = var_dump(intval($fila[0]));
        $p_producto = trim($_POST['producto_servicio']);
        $query_sql = "INSERT INTO tb_producto(id_compania, p_producto) VALUES ('$id_compania', '$p_producto')";
        if (mysqli_query($conn, $query_sql)) {
            header('location: product.php');
        } else {
            echo 'Ocurrio un error : ' . mysqli_error($conn);
        }
        mysqli_close($conn);
    }
}
}
```

Nota: tengo relacionada tb_compania con tb_producto como tendría que ser

Uso `MAX(ID)` Es muy util si vas a recuperar el ultimo id en cualquier momento y no solo después de insertarlo

Comment: Cuando haces `echo 'Su id es : ' . intval($fila[0]);`, que obtienes?

Comment: El error te está dando porque el ID de la compañía que estás insertando no existe en la tabla de compañía.
Veo que ya imprimes el valor del ID de la compañía, ¿te has asegurado de que existe dicho valor en la tabla de compañía? Un saludo!

Comment: Te falta insertar los datos de la idcompania antes porque estás intentando insertar datos en la tabla producto de una compañía que no existe.
Hoy en día con Frameworks como Laravel lo tendrías sencillísimo usando $query.

Comment: Me causa duda lo de Laravel y que sería fácil, un ejemplo ayudaría, ya que ahí query no parece más que una simple propiedad

Comment: @Alfabravo la respuesta es Su id es : 1 esa es la respuesta de echo.

Comment: @RubénEspada, Si, existe ya que cuando, ingreso con otro user, me genera el ID, de su dicha "empresa"

Comment: Para que sea una gran respuesta, coloca el código a manera de ejemplo de como se resolvería el problema.

Comment: todo estaba bien solo agregue el trim()  (https://subefotos.com/ver/?2e46006fe8bd6ac657225e6d64edca39o.png)